# How can you create a view as a post deployment script in a SQL Server Database Project?

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql

I've create a SQL Server Database Project and imported my database. I've got a few static data tables that I want to recreate every time it's redeployed, so these get recreated as part of the post deployment script.

To ensure this drops and recreates them I've changed these static data tables to have a build action of 'None' so they are dropped as part of the build and only recreated as part of post deployment steps.

My problem is that I have a view that references these tables. Obviously this shows syntax errors as the tables are no longer part of the build as their build action is 'None'. My workaround was to try and create the view also as part of the post deployment script. I do this with the following code:

```
:r .\PostDeploymentScripts\Views\myView.sql
```

The actual script looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [CompTotalByType] AS
SELECT
    c.Id,
    t.id AS TypeId,  
    SUM(c.total) AS CompTotal,
FROM CompNumber c
    INNER JOIN Type t 
    ON t.ProdId =  c.ProdId
GROUP BY
    c.Id,
    t.id
```

However, now I get a syntax error under 'CREATE VIEW' as follows:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       SQL72007: The syntax check failed 'Incorrect syntax near CREATE.' in the batch near:
>       'CREATE VIEW [CompTotalByType] AS' ....path name....

However, when I put this code into SSMS it has no syntax errors. What's causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer here: [SQL72007: The syntax check failed 'Unexpected end of file occurred.' in batch near :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925403/sql72007-the-syntax-check-failed-unexpected-end-of-file-occurred-in-batch-ne)

It was the second answer that said you needed to add a 'GO' to the previous script. This makes sense as the CREATE VIEW needs to be in its own batch. So I added a 'GO' to the bottom of my previous script before creating the view and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

How many static tables are you trying to recreate? I have a similar situation, but what I do instead is create 'MERGE' scripts using a stored procedure on Github called sp_generate_merge. Then I simply include those scripts within the project under a 'Scripts' folder and call them within the post-deployment script. That way you don't have to drop/create them, and your view and tables can be included in the build.

However, if you'd like to keep it the same - it seems that the other user is correct in saying that you need to add 'GO' before 'CREATE VIEW'.

Comment: It's 22 static data tables all in all. However, the main issue I had with those was that there were quite a few FK constraints. So, it was cleaner to drop the tables, recreate them without the FK constraints, insert the data and then add the FK constraints. This way it also preserved the ids, without having to turn on the IDENTITY_INSERT, which can be annoying because if you want to insert something in the middle of a long data table you then need to update all preceding ids. If I just deleted all the data and inserted it again the ids would start from the last iterated value.